# Java & SQL - XADataSource

Tags: java, sql-server, connection

We are running glassfish 4 for our java web application and are running into an issue with timers. Normal servlet calls are able to enjoy as many different connections as they want, which makes integrations much easier. Once we add timers however, the datasources need to be "XA" datasources instead. We set one up as such below:

```
public XADataSource getNewConnection() {
    Encapsulations encap = new Encapsulations();
    XADataSource ds = null;
    try {
        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
        if(!encap.getDataSource().equals("Production")){
              ds = (XADataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc/XA_TEST");
        }else{
              ds = (XADataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc/XA");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        CatchException.logException(null, e);
        String error = e.toString();
    }
    return ds;
}
```

The problem is that when the ds = (XADataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc/XA_TEST") line runs we get this error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.DataSource40 cannot be cast to javax.sql.XADataSource

We use the sqljdbc42 jar for our normal connections, so it is a bit strange to see 40 in there. Anyone know what the problem is? The datasource we are using was set up as an XADataSource, other than downloading a different jar I don't know what is missing.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I don't use Glassfish, but as far as I remember you should install the jar for your database provider that has the implementation of XADataSource interface. In MS SQL Server I've used the jTDS driver.

Another thing to consider from your code snippet is that you should have different configurations of glassfish for development and production, you should leave that kind of things to the application server and not inside your code. Glassfish is a full JavaEE Application Server, it has all the benefits including database connection pooling.

Comment: Our current jar has XADataSource. We're able to import it. The cast error is what is strange.

Comment: Does that class implements the XADataSource interface?

Comment: Also, in a JavaEE environment you should use something like this to use a Database `@PersistenceContext(unitName = "YourAwesome-pu")
    private EntityManager em;`

Comment: @Marcel Marino. I had met the same issue on my Payara 6. Do you find out any solution for it or other work around, if it is, please advise.

Comment: @cidy.long Yeah, stop using @ Schedule and call the timers from another source so that XA isn't required. Otherwise, no.

Comment: @Marcel Marino, THANK YOU FOR YOUR ADVICE. I tried to use TimerService instead of @ Schedule, it works for me. Thank you again.